# vs code cannot find path while runing c++ code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, error-handling, path

cd : Cannot find path 'C:\MinGW\binc\Users\Vinay Gole\Desktop\msi\apnacollege' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1

- cd "C:/MinGW/binc/Users/Vinay Gole/Desktop/msi/apnacollege/" ; if ($? ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\MinGW\binc\U...si\apnacollege\:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
  ```

Comment: Too little information. Please elaborate.  Is this post build command or some other place? Does path really exists?

Comment: this much of information i have

Comment: i dont know what happen to my vs code

Comment: please help me in this problem

Comment: I am sorry but as I have mentioned with the amount of information, it is impossible to help you.
I do not eve know if the path really exists. 
What I can deduce that you are using MinGW, and nothing else.
Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the names of all your files/folders in the directory and remove any emojis or non regular characters(such as ).
It might have caused the compiler to be unable to properly locate the .cpp file.
Cheers!